# why mongorestore hang when restore db in primary node?

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I built a simple master-slave replication:
members[0].priority = 10;
members[2].prority = 0 and members[2].salveDelay = 80000。
Then i try to restore dbs in primary node, the mongorestore command hang:
[image]

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Do you get more information when you run `mongorestore --verbose ...`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, in the primary node, i try to run command "db.dropDatabase()", it hangs

Answer (score 0):

For DDL's like `dropDatabase()` the `writeConcern` is "majority", you have to wait till it is propagated to secondary, i.e. 80'000 seconds which is **22.2 hours**!

See [db.dropDatabase() - Replica Set and Sharded Clusters](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.dropDatabase/#replica-set-and-sharded-clusters).

Same applies for `createIndex()` by default. However there you can specify [commitQuorum](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#std-label-createIndex-method-commitQuorum)